# Time travel novel with a robotic horse named N.E.S.T.O.R

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading a book in the late '80's early '90's  (it might even be a series) about a time traveler that travels back to medieval times.   The only character name I can remember is his robotic horse named N.E.S.T.O.R. or N.E.S.T.R.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Try to add as many details as you so our story-id experts have a better shot at answering this.

Comment: Part of me wants to suggest *The Warlock in Spite of Himself*, but the horse is named FESS, and it's an interplanetary travel thing, not time travel.

Comment: There's a TV Tropes for that: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MechanicalHorse

Comment: I let my wife read the book I am thinking of BUT I can not find were she put it. So mental prompts, Vikings, Mesopotamia a Rogue Group that wants to change time, they travel on a device that is more akin to a saddle than anything else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are both time travel and a robotic horse (but it's called Fess, from his serial number, not NESTOR) in Christopher Stasheff's [*The Warlock in Spite of Himself*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Warlock_in_Spite_of_Himself).

> The novel centers around Rod Gallowglass, a SCENT agent, who stumbles
>   across the planet Gramarye. Immediately upon landing he is thrust into
>   a world of medieval people, witches and warlocks, and all manner of
>   mythical creatures. Rod is aided by his faithful companion Fess, an
>   epileptic robot. While gathering intelligence, Rod discovers the
>   planet is in political turmoil, due to futurian influence on behalf of
>   the PEST and VETO organizations who plan to corrupt the planet away
>   from democracy, which Rod plans to bring to the planet, due to the
>   planet's importance to the future of the DDT. The three main factions
>   are the Monarchy led by Queen Catherine, the beggars led by Tuan
>   Loguire, and the Noble Lords eventually led by Anselm Loguire.

A "NESTOR" robot features in [a short story from Asimov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Lost_Robot) I re-read recently answering a question on WorldBuilding.SE, but it doesn't seem germane.

Comment: I do believe you found it.  Thank you so much, I've been trying off and on for a couple of years to find this.  After 30 years the details were extremely foggy but the split second I saw FESS (come on, NESTOR is sort of in the ballpark, right?) I knew this was the series.  As I read the description it jogged my memory and several details returned.  Once again, thank you for answering.

Answer (score 5):

Not a complete match, but there are distinct similarities to the [Conrad Stargard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conrad_Stargard) series of novels, by Leo Frankowsi, which start with *The Cross Time Engineer*.

Polish engineer Conrad Schwartz is accidentally sent back in time to medieval Poland. The team that accidentally sent him is unable to return him, but they are able to send him a number of high tech items to aid him, one of which is a robotic warhorse. I've been unable to find a name for the horse.

Conrad sets about trying to 'modify the timeline', particularly so that Medieval Europe will be able to resist the invasion of the Mongols.

Comment: Per TV Tropes (http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SapientSteed), it's name is Anna

Comment: I to kept finding this book but it never quite fell right.  Thank you for your answer and help.